# Questions viz. UEFI enabled post Ubuntu Mate installation while the Partitioning is still MBR

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, gpt, mbr

If 'UEFI Boot Support' is enabled in BIOS (was previously disabled) and if the 'Partitioning' is still 'MBR' then:

1. Would the OS boot?
2. If it boots, would there be any performance improvement?
3. Are there any potential complications that one should be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu MATE was installed in Legacy Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Without adding an EFI partition and then installing the EFI bootloader(s), you cannot boot in UEFI mode.  UEFI mode does not depend upon the disk partitioning type, but usually, UEFI is put on a gpt partitioned disk because Windows requires gpt for UEFI (Ubuntu does not care).  If your amchine allows a preference selection for mode (legacy before UEFI, or vice versa), then your machine should still boot (in legacy). If you machine settings only allow UEFI or legacy(CMS), then setting it to UEFI will not boot (no UEFI bootloaders).

Comment: Thank you ubfan1.